# Pegar tempo atual em Python

Tags: python, time

Pretendo calcular o tempo de execução de uma função em nanossegundos, dessa forma:

```
tempoIniAlg = time_ns()
vetorOrdenado = quickSort(vetor)  # Vetor ordenado
tempoAlg = time_ns()  # Tempo de resolução do algortimo
```

O problema é que com uma frequência relativamente alta, os campos `tempoIniAlg` e `tempoAlg` têm exatamente o mesmo valor, resultando em 0 o valor da diferença entre ambos, o que é impossível por N razões. Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma e não resolveu em nada:

```
tempoIniAlg = time_ns()
vetorOrdenado = quickSort(vetor)  # Vetor ordenado
tempoAlg = time_ns() - tempoIniAlg  # Tempo de resolução do algortimo
```

Não faço ideia do que possa ser.

Comment: Se quer medir o tempo de execução, pode usar o módulo `timeit`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a biblioteca `time` do Python

```
import time #importa a biblioteca 
start_time = time.time()    # pega o tempo de inicio 

i = 0 # variavel de exemplo 
while True: # loop de exemplo
    i = i + 1 # soma 
    print(i) # exibe qual o loop que está
    if i == 2: # define um máximo de 125 loops
        break # para o loop 

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) # faz a conta de quanto demorou para executar
```